# Printing red value of the image

Tags: python-3.x

```
 import cv2
 import glob
 import numpy as np
 print("Dude Test me \n")
 sample_folder=input("Enter the image containg folder you want to test :  ")
 sample_image=input("Enter image name(number) : ")
 print(str(sample_image)+'.png')
 for i in glob.glob('E:\dataset\TRAINING DATA\small\a\str(sample_image)+'.png''):
     img1=cv2.imread(i)
     b,g,r=cv2.split(img1)
     red_value1=np.array(r)
     dup_input_vector1=red_value1.reshape(7990,1)
     dup_input_vector1[dup_input_vector1==255]=1
     print(dup_input_vector1.shape)
```

am i used str() function correctly?..if i give input image as 2..it should take the 2.png image and print its red value alone..help me..